# "/phpMyAdmin/index.php was not found on this server" error

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, php

I am trying to run phpmyadmin on ubuntu 9.04
I installed phpmyadmin through apt-get install and configured it to use apache-2

php files can be run correctly
mysql server is set up properly

I can't figure out what's wrong...
Can somebody help?

Comment: Where is the actual `phpMyAdmin` folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run

```
ln -s /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf /etc/apache2/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

and use your web browser to go to http://server.address/phpmyadmin/

to be on the safe side - configure it manually to one non-default vhost and even better - set apache rules to limit access to it only from trusted subnet.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. It works !!!
I wonder why apt doesn't handles this...